# Need help removing Ubuntu from a single boot hard disk

Tags: system-installation, usb, windows, uninstall

I bought a used PC recently (an old hp 8200 elite) that arrived with ubuntu 19.10 installed.

I never used It and I want to install windows istead. The problem is I can't do anything on this os. Everything I try doesn't work.

The PC boots directly to ubuntu. There's no a second partition. I can't use windows tools since I can't open `.exe` files.

- I tried Woeusb but after 1 hour of "installing for i386-pc" I gave up.
- I tried to format manually, the usb drive I downloaded other programs since there was no a format option, nor I knew the command if there is one. After 40 minutes it gave me an error.

I feel like I never used a PC in my life. It's so frustrating.

Can you guys please help me?

Comment: @Jimmy Verdura Why are you installing for i-386? Try 64bit, woeusb_3.3.1-1~webupd8~eoan0_amd64.deb or ask a friend to make you a USB using media tool from Microsoft

Comment: @Graham Which answer on that page do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple google search for "how to create a windows installation media". Set the computer bios to boot with the USB drive or DVD media (whichever you choose). The installation media will take it from there.

This is not a Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Already did, the research suggests me to use woeusb. I cant use the media tool from microsoft since its a .exe.